# notepad on top of a winform

Tags: c#, winforms

good day guys, can anyone help me. I have a winforms that set `TopMost = true`. And I have a button that when I click it, it create a notepad. Now, I want my notepad to show at the top of my winforms **without** setting my winforms TopMost = false. Maybe I've miss something. I'm open for any suggestions. By the way I set my form to `TopMost=true` and `BringToFront()` because I don't want any user to select any program at the taskbar and bring it to front and minimize my winforms. Thanks in advance

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BringToFront();
    this.TopMost = true;
}

// bunch of codes here...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    process.Start();

}

// some codes here

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    Left = Top = 0;
    Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;  
}
```

Comment: Tried the `SendToBack` method yet?

Comment: The only option I can see is to get NotePad main window handle: `process.MainWindowHandle` then via `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong` add `WS_EX_TOPMOST` extended window style to it

Comment: @kevintjuh93 tried it just now, the notepad in front now, but the winform is on the back of my browser(open before i run my application)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I think i  read it a while ago. I think it will only run if my topmost is false. but it wont take effect if it's true... Right? you have snipped code there... it really help

Comment: @kevintjuh93 Thank you for your help I really appreciate it..

Comment: @DmitryBychenko. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*PInvoke* solution:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...

// Even if it is "user32.dll" it will do on IA64 as well
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, 
                                int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

 ...

// Since Process is IDisposable, put it into "using"
using (Process process = new Process()) {
  process.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
  process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
  process.Start();

  // wait for main window be created
  process.WaitForInputIdle();

  // Insert (change Z-order) as the topmost - (IntPtr) (-1); 
  // NoMove, NoSize - 0x0002 | 0x0001
  SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr) (-1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0002 | 0x0001);
}
```